# Get DCT (Discrete Cosine Transform) of image on Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I have a problem on how to compute the DCT of 8*8 bock of image on android. I'm using opencv on my android project and can't find proper method for getting dct.

can anyone know how to compute this ?
is there any method for doing this on android or I should compute dct formula by my own?

note that I know how to get DCT of image on original opencv (with cv2.dct()) but I have trouble on android ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link:

[Convert OpenCv DFT example from C++ to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123502/convert-opencv-dft-example-from-c-to-android)

you can replace the dft call with a call to Core.dct