# OpenCV - Converting DCT on C++ to Android : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 thrown

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to convert a C++ DCT code to Android. Below is the code that I have tried to convert from C++ to OpenCV on Android. However, I obtain this error:

> Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

I found out that the "outplanes" is 0. Is it possible to set ArrayList size or am I missing something? To be honest, I am not particularly sure this code will work or not. Please advise me on what I should do. Thank you so much!

```
Mat secondImage = new Mat();
secondImage = image.clone();

List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();

Core.split(secondImage, planes);
List<Mat> outplanes = new ArrayList<Mat>(planes.size());         
Mat trans = new Mat(CvType.CV_32FC1);           
Log.d("Planes", Integer.toString(planes.size())); //3
Log.d("Outplanes", Integer.toString(outplanes.size()));
for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) { 
    planes.get(k).convertTo(planes.get(k),CvType.CV_32FC1); 
    Core.dct(planes.get(k), outplanes.get(k)); 
    outplanes.get(k).convertTo(outplanes.get(k),CvType.CV_8UC1);  
} 

Core.merge(outplanes, trans);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call:

```
List<Mat> outplanes = new ArrayList<Mat>(planes.size());
```

will not dimension all you Mats for you - the parameter to the constructor is just a guide to how much memory you think you might eventually need. It doesn't matter if it turns out that you need more; the ArrayList will redimension as you add items but it is slightly more performant to tell it how large the array will be if you know this beforehand.

So, you still need to add Mats to the array list for the size as measured by planes.size() to increase. For example, if I do:

```
    outplanes.addAll(planes);
```

after you initialise outplanes, then the error goes away.

Also look at this:

[Get DCT (Discrete Cosine Transform) of image on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765711/get-dct-discrete-cosine-transform-of-image-on-android/21766713#21766713)