# Convert OpenCv DCT to Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement a DCT code in Android. I'm testing out using the code but just changing to DCT instead of DFT : [Convert OpenCv DFT example from C++ to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123502/convert-opencv-dft-example-from-c-to-android). There have been changes to the code, thanks to timegalore. Now I'm having problems converting the image back to BGR.

```
public void transformImage(){
image = Highgui.imread(imageName, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);      
try {
    secondImage = new Mat(image.rows(), image.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);
    image.convertTo(secondImage, CvType.CV_64FC1);

    int m = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(image.rows());
    int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(image.cols()); // on the border add zero values

    Mat padded = new Mat(new Size(n, m), CvType.CV_64FC1); // expand input image to optimal size

    Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(secondImage, padded, 0, m - secondImage.rows(), 0, n - secondImage.cols(), Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT);

    Mat result = new Mat(padded.size(), padded.type());
    Core.dct(padded, result);

    Mat transformedImage = new Mat(padded.size(), padded.type());
    Core.idct(result, watermarkedImage);

    completedImage = new Mat(image.rows(), image.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(transformedImage, completedImage, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Blargh", e.toString());
}
```

}

Now, I have obtained this error

> 04-09 21:35:52.362: E/cv::error()(23460): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F) in void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3642

I am not sure what I should do, please advise. Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line:

```
image.convertTo(secondImage, CvType.CV_64FC1);
```

but then you don't use secondImage again, just image. Try:

```
Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(secondImage, padded, 0, m - secondImage.rows(), 0, n - secondImage.cols(), Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT);
```

and see how you get on.

Also DCT looks like it only works on reals not complex numbers like DFT and so you don't need to add a second channel to zero the imaginary part. You can work directly with the padded variable, so:

```
Mat result = new Mat(padded.size(), padded.type());
```

then

```
Core.dct(padded, result);
```

also, the original image needs to be single channel - so a greyscale. When you call Highgui.imread the image that will be loaded is multichannel - on my device it is 3 channel in BGR format. You can convert it to greyscale using Imgproc.cvtColor but it would be simpler just to load it as grey scale in the first place:

```
image = Highgui.imread(imageName, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: haha thanks for noticing that. but it throws me this exception now : Assertion failed (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1) in void cv::dct(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp, line 2281
I would assume the cvType is wrong right?

Comment: thanks for the update. but I am still getting this : Assertion failed (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1) in void cv::dct(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp, line 2281. What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: I've added some further info to the end of the original answer - see how you get on.

Comment: oh I see. thanks, I will try it out. is it possible if I want to convert the image back to BGR format?

Comment: Oh yes, it works! Thank you so much! Would the process of idct be the same as this?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not. You can also call dct with the Core.DCT_INVERSE flag, which has the same effect. Good luck with your project - glad I could help.

Comment: thank you so much for spending your time helping me. if there is any questions, I might ask it over here again. thanks again!

Comment: I used cvtColor to convert back the image, but I got this error when changing back to BGR format - Assertion failed (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F) in void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3642. I'll edit the code to show what I've done

Comment: The results of idct will be a 64 bit floating point number. To visualise this you will need to normalise it to numbers in the range 0 to 255. Also, note that as the results are in greyscale converting to BGR form will still be grey but if you need a 3 channel result then fine. The normalisation process can be seen in the "Convert OpenCv DFT example from C++ to Android" thread.

Comment: so there is no other way to get back the image to it's original BGR colour?

Comment: You could apply the process to each B, G and R channel individually and recombine into one image at the end.

Comment: how do i obtain each channel's value?

Comment: use Core.split and then Core.merge to combine back again.

Comment: I got this trying that out. haha. Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000015 (code=1)

Comment: probably best to ask a new question with the code extract and we can look at that problem separately

Comment: I've posted up a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984465/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x00000015-code-1-when-implementing-split-and-mer