# OpenCv - Implementing split and merge for DCT

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement a DCT code in Android. I'm using the split and merge method to obtain the original colors of the image.

Here is the snippet of the code

```
image = Highgui.imread(imageName);  

secondImage = new Mat(image.rows(), image.cols(), CvType.CV_32FC3);
image.convertTo(secondImage, CvType.CV_32FC3);

int m = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(image.rows());
int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(image.cols()); // on the border add zero values

Mat padded = new Mat(new Size(n, m), CvType.CV_32FC3); // expand input image to optimal size

Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(secondImage, padded, 0, m - secondImage.rows(), 0, n - secondImage.cols(), Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT);

List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();

Core.split(padded, planes);
List<Mat> outplanes = new ArrayList<Mat>(planes.size());
for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) { 
    outplanes.add(new Mat(padded.size(), CvType.CV_32FC1)); 
} 

Mat trans = new Mat(padded.size(), padded.type());  

for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) { 
    Core.dct(planes.get(k), outplanes.get(k));  
} 

List<Mat> ioutplanes = new ArrayList<Mat>(outplanes.size());
for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) { 
    ioutplanes.add(new Mat(padded.size(), CvType.CV_32FC1)); 
}   

for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) {
    Core.idct(outplanes.get(k), ioutplanes.get(k));  
} 
Core.merge(ioutplanes, trans);
```

This time got this exception :

> The function/feature is not implemented (Odd-size DCT's are not implemented) in void cv::dct(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp, line 2330

Is this code correct? Your help is very much appreciated.

**Updated:** I noticed that the copyMakeBorder() is the one that caused my image size to be odd, that is why I am having this exception.

Answer (score 0):

[SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) is a segmentation fault, generally thrown when a program tries to access a part of the memory it doesn't have permission or is otherwise unable to access. My thoughts is that this is due to hardware, perhaps too little memory for the operations.

Have you tried running the program with smaller samples, or on a different machine?

Comment: I've tried with smaller samples, and it gave me that same error as well. Never tried on another machine yet.

Answer (score 0):

secondImage and padded will want to be of type: CvType.CV_32FC3. Also the in-situ conversion like:

```
   planes.get(k).convertTo(planes.get(k), CvType.CV_32FC1);
```

I'm not sure will work so use an intermediate Mat if you need to do this sort of conversion. Note also that padded is already CV_32F so not sure you need to do this conversion. Likewise the output from dct - if this is CV_32F then no need to convert.

If you want to display the merged picture you will of course need to normalise each channels values to between 0 and 255.

It looks like you are applying the dct transform and then the inverse straight after so you will get back what you started with. I think also we need to be careful about calls like outplanes.addAll(planes) as I think this will just add references to the objects rather than allocating the space, which is really what you want.

Try this:

```
Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(secondImage, padded, 0,
                m - secondImage.rows(), 0, n - secondImage.cols(),
                Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT);

List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();

Core.split(padded, planes);

Mat trans = new Mat(padded.size(), padded.type());

List<Mat> ioutplanes = new ArrayList<Mat>(planes.size());

for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) {
    ioutplanes.add(new Mat(padded.size(), CvType.CV_32FC1));
}

for (int k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) {
    Core.idct(planes.get(k), ioutplanes.get(k));
}

Core.merge(ioutplanes, trans);
```

Comment: I've removed the line and it is still working. Should I split again for the idct part? And I should normalise each channels before merging them or after? I tried it myself by splitting the image again and normalise the merged image, however the image i got has a weird glow effect. I guess I did something wrong that might have caused that glow effect.

Comment: i added the idct part after i dct the image (without splitting it again). the image turn out to be normal though. is it done right?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you normalise before or after. Note that when I use imread it comes in as BGR but when I need to display it needs to be RGB so I need to do a little conversion when I load a file using imread. I'll try the code tonight - do you have a copy of the source image you are processing?

Comment: what my code actually does is read the image from the image taken by the camera. so it's just a random image.

Comment: well, the main purpose was to do invisible watermarking after performing DCT on the image. that was why I just test out the DCT and iDCT part. I understand that I should implement the watermarking stuff after DCT then inverse it back to the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change this code

```
int m = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(image.rows());
int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(image.cols());
```

to

```
int m =Core.getOptimalDFTSize((image.rows()+1)/2)*2;
int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize((image.cols()+1)/2)*2;
```

in order to get the odd size for DCT, since this function is for DFT.

It is written in the function documentation from the website as this:

While the function cannot be used directly to estimate the optimal vector size for DCT transform (since the current DCT implementation supports only even-size vectors), it can be easily processed as getOptimalDFTSize((vecsize+1)/2)*2.