# Load Image in Mat and Display after DFT process

Tags: android, image, opencv, matrix, dft

I got a problem loading image (in list/on click) in Mat on Android, and processing with OpenCV DFT function then return result.

This is my src
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static final String CAMERA_PIC_DIR = "/DCIM/Camera/";
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    String ImageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + CAMERA_PIC_DIR;

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ListFile.class);
    i.putExtra( "directory", ImageDir);
    startActivityForResult(i,0);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        String tmp = data.getExtras().getString("clickedFile");
        //Bitmap ImageToChange= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmp);
        //Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ImageToChange, 480, 320, false);
        Mat mRgba = new Mat();
        mRgba = Highgui.imread(tmp);
        getDFT(mRgba);
        //iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

If i uncomment 2 Line of Bitmap and iv.set , image successfully load and display list image after click.

and this is getDFT method, still on MainActivity.java

```
private Mat getDFT(Mat singleChannel) {

    singleChannel.convertTo(singleChannel, CvType.CV_64FC1);

    int m = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(singleChannel.rows());
    int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(singleChannel.cols()); // on the border
                                                    // add zero
                                                    // values
                                                    // Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(image1,
                                                    // padded, 0, m -
                                                    // image1.rows(), 0, n

    Mat padded = new Mat(new Size(n, m), CvType.CV_64FC1); // expand input
                                                            // image to
                                                            // optimal size

    Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(singleChannel, padded, 0, m - singleChannel.rows(), 0,
            n - singleChannel.cols(), Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT);

    List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    planes.add(padded);
    planes.add(Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1));

    Mat complexI = Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC2);

    Mat complexI2 = Mat
            .zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC2);

    Core.merge(planes, complexI); // Add to the expanded another plane with
                                    // zeros

    Core.dft(complexI, complexI2); // this way the result may fit in the
                                    // source matrix

    // compute the magnitude and switch to logarithmic scale
    // => log(1 + sqrt(Re(DFT(I))^2 + Im(DFT(I))^2))
    Core.split(complexI2, planes); // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] =
                                    // Im(DFT(I))

    Mat mag = new Mat(planes.get(0).size(), planes.get(0).type());

    Core.magnitude(planes.get(0), planes.get(1), mag);// planes[0]
                                                        // =
                                                        // magnitude

    Mat magI = mag;
    Mat magI2 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
    Mat magI3 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
    Mat magI4 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
    Mat magI5 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());

    Core.add(magI, Mat.ones(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1),
            magI2); // switch to logarithmic scale
    Core.log(magI2, magI3);

    Mat crop = new Mat(magI3, new Rect(0, 0, magI3.cols() & -2,
            magI3.rows() & -2));

    magI4 = crop.clone();

    // rearrange the quadrants of Fourier image so that the origin is at the
    // image center
    int cx = magI4.cols() / 2;
    int cy = magI4.rows() / 2;

    Rect q0Rect = new Rect(0, 0, cx, cy);
    Rect q1Rect = new Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy);
    Rect q2Rect = new Rect(0, cy, cx, cy);
    Rect q3Rect = new Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy);

    Mat q0 = new Mat(magI4, q0Rect); // Top-Left - Create a ROI per quadrant
    Mat q1 = new Mat(magI4, q1Rect); // Top-Right
    Mat q2 = new Mat(magI4, q2Rect); // Bottom-Left
    Mat q3 = new Mat(magI4, q3Rect); // Bottom-Right

    Mat tmp = new Mat(); // swap quadrants (Top-Left with Bottom-Right)
    q0.copyTo(tmp);
    q3.copyTo(q0);
    tmp.copyTo(q3);

    q1.copyTo(tmp); // swap quadrant (Top-Right with Bottom-Left)
    q2.copyTo(q1);
    tmp.copyTo(q2);

    Core.normalize(magI4, magI5, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX);

    Mat realResult = new Mat(magI5.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

    magI5.convertTo(realResult, CvType.CV_8UC1);

    return realResult;
}
```

and This is my ListFile.java

```
public class ListFile extends ListActivity {
private List<String> directoryEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    File directory = new File(i.getStringExtra("directory"));

    if (directory.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        //sort in descending date order
        Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return -Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified())
                .compareTo(f2.lastModified());
            }
        });

        //fill list with files
        this.directoryEntries.clear();
        for (File file : files){
            this.directoryEntries.add(file.getPath());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.file_row, this.directoryEntries);
        //alphabetize entries
        //directoryList.sort(null);
        this.setListAdapter(directoryList);
        }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    File clickedFile = new File(this.directoryEntries.get(pos));
    Intent i = getIntent();
    i.putExtra("clickedFile", clickedFile.toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

}

Android Successfully running, but after I click one of my choice image, android stopped working,
This is the Logcat ouput

```
W/dalvikvm(14245): No implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;.n_Mat:()J
D/AndroidRuntime(14245): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(14245): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cbb9c0)
E/AndroidRuntime(14245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14245): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J
```

Link Reference:

> [android dft got hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010407/android-dft-function-got-hang-and-stopped-working)
>
> [Convert Opencv DFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123502/convert-opencv-dft-example-from-c-to-android/20807824#20807824)

Comment: Did you trace your code?

Comment: @Constantine do you mean debug?
i don't really know how to trace the code. please give your suggestion

Comment: yes, put a `breakpoint` run debugger, trace variable values. most of the times that will solve our problems with codes :)

Comment: It could be a race condition with the loading of openCV. You should wait for openCV library to load before using any of the structures like Mat. I don't see where you call OpenCVLoader.initAsync - usually this is in onResume and then you can get going when the callback returns LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS.

Comment: Hello.. after i learn about trace the code(debug).  
  i'm finally know what the problem within my code.

[link](http://example.com)

Comment: thank's @timegalore, that the hint for solving problem.

Comment: thank's @Constantine, debug is very entertaining and very important thing :)